# Find whether list element occurs 2 times?

Tags: python, list

I'm helping with an assignment that is supposed to accomplish this. This is a simple problem, but it calls for the use of the `index()` function and the slice function. I'm at a loss as to how to do this. I'm not sure why those two functions would be needed to do something like this. With that said, could anyone share some knowledge of how this could be done?

Comment: Do you _have_ to use `index` and `slice`?

Comment: @icodez For this problem, yes I do. It's a learning thing I suppose.

Comment: Oh, ok.  I was going to say why not use `.count` if not.

Comment: @icodez I can do this with for loops, but again, not sure how to like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 5]
>>> any(item in L[L.index(item)+1:] for item in L)
True
>>> L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5]
>>> any(item in L[L.index(item)+1:] for item in L)
False
```

If you really need to use the `slice` *function* instead of just slicing

```
>>> any(item in L[slice(L.index(item)+1, None)] for item in L)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely have to use `index` and slices, you can write

```
def occurs_twice(lst, elem):
    try:
        i1 = lst.index(elem)
    except ValueError:
        return False

    try:
        i2 = lst[i1+1:].index(elem)
    except ValueError:
        return False

    return True

print occurs_twice([1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 5], 5)
```

Comment: I think he meant the `slice` function, as in the built-in.

Comment: Uhh, I guess you can write ``lst[slice(i1+1)]`` instead of ``lst[i1+1:]``, but it's essentially the same thing.

Comment: I know.  I was just questioning whether his teachers would ding him for that.

Comment: @icodez If they're the same thing I don't think it's a big deal.